# How can I know when my tomcat web application stopped?

Tags: tomcat

I want to get an 'event' before tomcat stops my web application.
My application needs to "wrap up" stuff before it is being closed.

Comment: how are you starting / stopping it?  What OS?  What does "Wrap up" mean?  Is that java code that needs to be executed?

Comment: I need to send a message (using simple UDP socket) to nitify that the application is being stopped.
I'm running tomcat in Linux (Ubuntu). 
yes, my application is Java servlet based application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found it, I created a servlet and implemented the

```
public void destroy();
```

I verified that this method is invoked when I stop the application from the tomcat admin page, and even when I shut-down tomcat server

[JavaEE 6 doc on Servlets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#destroy%28%29)

Answer (score 5):

A servlet that does nothing but respond to `destroy()` is functional but a bit of a hack. Servlets are meant to handle web requests.

The proper thing to do is to implement a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and do your wrap up stuff in the `contextDestroyed()` method.

Register your `ServletContextListener` in web.xml like:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.foo.MyListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a ContextListener that responds to deploy/undeploy events.  Maybe you can have it sends an email when the context is undeployed.

I'm just not sure if that event is fired if the app server is stopped.